# Issue with upgrading to Rails 5 - before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I know that before_filter is deprecated with rails. I'm not calling it but for some reason I'm getting a message that is saying I am. `before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/intern/Desktop/Work/app/config/environment.rb:5)`

In that file `environment.rb` on line 5 I'm not calling before filter but this line `Rails.application.initialize!`

Why would it be saying that a before filter is being used when it's not being called there? Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the gems is using it. Or you, in other controllers. Replace all your usages of `before_filter` to `before_action` and pray that all your gems are maintained enough to do the same before this becomes an error.

Comment: So, when `Rails` is called that is calling all my gems and code?

Comment: Because my I'm not using it in my project and no gem is using to my knowledge.

Comment: Initializing the application does mean loading your gems, yes.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks

Comment: Do you know of a way I can find out which gem may be using it?

Comment: You can pry them open one by one by using `bundle open gemname`. Not the most efficient way, certainly.

Comment: Yikes yeah...That's good to know though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You can find offending gems files using this snippet. Replace the path with your own gempath.

```
grep -rn --color=always --include=*.rb "[\.|\:|\s]before_filter " ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems
```